# Create three files programmatically with python using argparse and multiprocessor

Tags: python, python-3.x

My goal is to output 3 files named `file_1.py` `file_2.py` `file_3.py` using the following code.

## The problem

However, when I call the `generate_file(100,1)` function with `100` and `3` as arguments, I receive the following **error**:

`error: the following arguments are required: num_files, num_lines`

```py
import random
import argparse
import multiprocessing


# Function to generate a file with the specified number of lines
def generate_file(num_lines, file_number):
    '''
    Function to generate a file with the specified number of lines, each with 3 random numbers
    '''
    filename = "file_" + str(file_number) + ".txt"

    # Open writer and output lines
    file = open(filename, "w")
    for i in range(num_lines):
        line = str(random.randint(0, 10)) + " " + str(random.randint(0, 10)) + " " + str(random.randint(0, 10))
        file.write(line + "\n")
    file.close()
    print(filename + " written!")
```

I then use this code to generate three individual files programmatically:

```py
def parse_arguments():
    '''
    Argument parser
    num_files = Number of files
    num_lines = Number of lines
    '''
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Set the number of files and number of lines')
    parser.add_argument("num_files", type=int, help="Number of files to create")
    parser.add_argument("num_lines", type=int, help="Number of lines per file")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return (args)


def main():
    '''
    Get arguments from func, setup multiprocessing, create files
    '''
    arguments = parse_arguments()
    num_files = arguments.num_files
    num_lines = arguments.num_lines
    print("Program arguments: num_files = " + str(num_files) + "; num_lines = " + str(num_lines))

    jobs = []
    for file_number in range(num_files):
        t = multiprocessing.Process(target=generate_file, args=(num_lines, file_number))
        jobs.append(t)
        t.start()  # new child process is started at this point, it has its own execution flow

    for curr_job in jobs:  # wait for all processes to finish
        curr_job.join()

    print("Program completed OK")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And then I call the function:

```py
#call function
generate_file(100, 3)
```

Comment: How are you executing this python script? I tried running your script in the command line and it parsed the arguments correctly: e.g. 'python file.py 100 3'

Comment: @Imeninato I was calling the function within the file e.g., 'generate_file(100,3)' Can you explain how/why you feed the file the args when you execute via the terminal? In other words, I'm definitely not understanding a piece of this code. A brief explanation would be super helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call processes generated with multiprocessing with an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard. See here for more: [Python multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming). Check the section labeled

> Safe importing of main module

Comment: Thank you for this! Very helpful!